# Coordinate vector and curve

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems

How can I see that the $j$-th coordinate vector $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$$ on a manifold is the **velocity** vector to the $j$-th coordinate curve parametrized by $x^j$. Both, by velocity and direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if $p \in M$ and $(U,x(\cdot))$ is a chart on the manifold containing the point $p$, then the tangent vector $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p \in T_pM$ is equal to the equivalence class of curves $[t \mapsto x^{-1}(x(p) + t e_j)]$, in other words, in $\Bbb{R}^n$ you consider the straight line $x(p)+ t e_j$ parallel to the $j^{th}$ coordinate axis, and then you "lift it back up" to the get a curve in manifold using $x^{-1}$.

Comment: What is the equivalence relation in your answer : "[ ... ]" ?

Comment: @user122424 The equivalence relation is defined on the set of all smooth curves $\gamma:I \to M$, $I$ being an open interval in $\Bbb{R}$ containing $0$, such that $\gamma(0) = p$. Now, we define two curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ through $p$ to be equivalent, denoted $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2$, if there is a chart $(U,x(\cdot))$ around the point $p$ such that $(x \circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (x \circ \gamma_2)'(0)$. Using chain rule, one can show that this construction is chart independent. So, in words, two curves are equivalent if in some (and hence every) chart, they have the same velocity vector.

Comment: An equivalent way of describing the above equivalence relation is as follows (when I say this is an equivalent approach, I mean that both these constructions yield the same equivalence classes of curves): define two smooth curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ passing through the point $p$ to be equivalent, denoted $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2$, if for every smooth function $f:M \to \Bbb{R}$, we have $(f \circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (f \circ \gamma_2)'(0)$. This is clearly a chart-independent construction.